# Definition of quasi-harmonic map

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

What is the definition of *quasi-harmonic maps* between two Riemannian manifolds?

Any reference will be highly appreciated!

Comment: There are references in [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2002-130-11/S0002-9939-02-06499-7/S0002-9939-02-06499-7.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a smooth map $\phi:(M,g)\to(N,h)$ between two Riemannian manifolds $(M,g)$ and $(N,h)$, its *energy* $E(\phi)$ is defined by
$$E(\phi)={1\over 2}\int_M |d\phi(x)|^2\;dM,$$
where $|d\phi(x)|^2$ is the square of the norm of the differential $d\phi(x)$ at a point $x\in M$.

A map $\phi:(M,g)\to(N,h)$ is called *harmonic* if $\phi$ is a critical point of the energy functional $E$.

In the literature, one can also find the notion of *quasi-harmonic* map. Suppose that $N$ is a smooth compact Riemannian manifold. We call $\phi:(M,g)\to(N,h)$ a quasi-harmonic map, if $\phi$ is a non-constant smooth map which is a critical point of the *quasi-energy* functional $E_q$ with respect to any smooth compactly supported variation, where
$$E_q(\phi)={1\over 2}\int_M |d\phi(x)|^2e^{-{|y|^2\over 4}}\;dy.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. So, in a way, a quasi-harmonic map  from M to N is an harmonic map from M endowed with that gaussian density to N. 
Why are quasi-harmonic maps studied? I can see that if M and N are Eucludean spaces, the Euler-Lagrange equation given by the quasi-energy is the drifted-Laplace equation. But what is the general motivation?

Comment: @Onil90 I presume that the study of this energy has some kind of physical meaning, but unfortunately I can't give you more details. I study harmonic maps in geometry as part of my research, and I knew that there were some other *harmonic-like* maps derived from changing the Dirichlet energy, but I don't know the details about their motivation.

Comment: Your $|y|^2$ dont quite make sense to me. Should it be a distance function on $M$ instead?

Comment: @Onil90 : In mean curvature flow, the singularity model is more or less a critical points of such a drifted harmonic equations. Similar happens for Ricci flow and I believe also for other flows.

Comment: @JohnMa You are talking about the fact that shrinking solitons (which model the type I singularities) can be viewed as minimal surfaces w.r.t. that Gaussian density, right? Where can I find this phrased in terms of quasi harmonic maps?

Comment: In Colding-Minicozzi's work [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.2594.pdf). Or more explicitly in my work on branched self-shrinkers in dimension 2 (see section 4 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.07563.pdf)) @Onil90

Comment: @JohnMa Thanks a lot! I will definitely take a look!